# Performance issue with custom listview in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-custom-view

I used View-Holder class for displaying custom list view.In some devices like Galaxy S3,S4 the scrolling in list view will be very slow.In some devices it's very fast.I don't know why it's not scrolling fast in S3 and S4.Please can any one help me.

Here My code is:

```
public class doctortAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return doctorData_list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View view = convertView;
            final RecordHolder holder;
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);

                holder = new RecordHolder();

                holder.txtName = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
                holder.txtAddress1 = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_address);
                holder.txtAddress2 = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_address1);
                holder.btn_book = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_book);
                holder.btn_advice = (Button) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.button_advice);
                holder.btn_favourite = (Button) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.button_faviourate);
                holder.txtReview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                holder.img_personPic = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.rt = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
                holder.btn_book.setFocusable(false);
                holder.btn_advice.setFocusable(false);
                holder.btn_favourite.setFocusable(false);
                holder.rt.setFocusable(false);

                holder.rt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            DoctorData doc_data = doctorData_list.get(position);
                            selected_doctorID = doc_data.getDocID();

                            if (checkSession() == true) {
                                addReview();
                            } else {
                                ratingBarDialog();
                            }
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                });

                holder.btn_favourite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        DoctorData doc_data = doctorData_list.get(position);
                        doctorid = doc_data.getDocID();
                        if (checkSession() == true) {
                            favouriteDialog();
                        } else {
                            // ratingBarDialog();
                            signInDialog();
                        }

                    }
                });

                holder.btn_book.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        DoctorData doc_data = doctorData_list.get(position);
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                DoctorDetailsActivity.class).putExtra(
                                "doctorData", doc_data).putExtra(
                                "TabSelection", "schedule"));
                        Editor prefsEditor = pref.edit();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String json = gson.toJson(doc_data);
                        prefsEditor.putString("doctorData", json);
                        prefsEditor.commit();
                        finish();


                    }
                });

                holder.btn_advice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                FreeAdviceActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                holder.txtReview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        DoctorData doc_data = doctorData_list.get(position);
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                DoctorDetailsActivity.class).putExtra(
                                "doctorData", doc_data).putExtra(
                                "TabSelection", "review"));
                        Editor prefsEditor = pref.edit();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String json = gson.toJson(doc_data);
                        prefsEditor.putString("doctorData", json);
                        prefsEditor.commit();
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (RecordHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            DoctorData doc_data = doctorData_list.get(position);
            holder.txtName.setText(doc_data.getFirstName() + " "
                    + doc_data.getLastName());
            holder.txtAddress1.setText(doc_data.getAddress1());
            holder.txtAddress2.setText(doc_data.getAddress2());

            return view;
        }

    }

    public class RecordHolder {
        TextView txtName, txtAddress1, txtAddress2, txtReview;
        ImageView img_personPic;
        Button btn_book, btn_favourite, btn_advice;
        RatingBar rt;
    }
```

custom listview code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/defaultprofilepic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="No Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_advice"
                style="@style/buttons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Free Advice" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_book"
                style="@style/buttons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_faviourite"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_faviourite"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="$0 Book 0nline" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="No address"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_address1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_address"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="No address"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            style="@style/foodRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_address1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_address1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_faviourate"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_name"
            android:background="@drawable/favoirate_selector" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:text="Reviews"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#07a3d3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and mainActicity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/doctor" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/location" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/insurance" />
        </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>

 <TableLayout
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Speciality"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/new_header" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_privious"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_date"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_date"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/leftarrow" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_date"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_date"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rightarrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_date"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_next"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_next_call1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

    </ListView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_custom_progresswheel"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next_call1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Next" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder_backbutton"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_previous"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Previous" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder_backbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting your all data in ListView?

Comment: yes , i am getting all data in listview but when i scrolling it is very slow in s3 and s4.

Comment: make viewHolder static, Just add static identifier before class, public static class viewHolder{ ...... }

Comment: I added static before class,but same thing happens...it's happens only in Galaxy S3 and S4.Some devices it's works fine.

Comment: Hey did you get the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and I found out:--

I found out that you are fetching layoutinflator every time your view is null so first  you move that code to your adapter constuctor and use that layoutInflator.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

declare it in as instance variable of adapter class and then use that.

To make your scrolling fast you can use this code:--

```
     getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

Hope this helps..enjoy..!

#### Update:-

I checked your xml and your code, everything is fine i think the problem is your listview row having many view which you are getting findviewbyid() which takes a time so may be you need to optimize that.Remove those View findViewById() which you are not using for display.

Comment: I used this code:    LayoutInflater inflater;
  public doctortAdapter() {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);               
  } ,but scrolling is slow.

Comment: have you removed the assigning code of layoutinflater from getview?

Comment: if (view == null) {
    
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);}  I have written code like this way

Comment: ok you removed and still not working..:? ok can you post your xml code pls

Answer (score 0):

set all the onclick out side the `if`

after this:

```
  } else {
                holder = (RecordHolder) view.getTag();
            }
  //set all the onClick listener
```

Answer (score 0):

What is doctorData_list? is its get method's time complexity O(1)?

Pass in the parent ViewGroup when inflating (but don't add it to the root):

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);
```

Don't nest RelativeLayouts, they cause exponential layout passes which is really not nice in a ListView
The root for your listview item looks like it can be a vertical LinearLayout, and the root for the Activity could be a FrameLayout with a LinearLayout inside it?

Return `doctorData_list.get(position)` in `getItem`

Return `position` in `getItemId`

Save the position into the view's tag outside of the `if(view == null)/else` condition. Read that tag in the `onClick`, `onTouch`, etc methods out of the view that is passed into those methods.
Currently, your buttons will use the position that the view was first created for - if you scroll down and they get recycled, when you click on something in position X, it will update the data for a different position.

Comment: If your doctorData_list is large and doesn't support constant time gets, this is probably your problem. If your doctorData_list is something like an ArrayList it should be fine and there is something else using the UI thread which is causing it to be slow - with these changes your adapter is fine